# How to deal with AnimatedList when Last Item rebuild on deleting an item in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Iam trying to make a List of countdown timers and adding and removing it dynamically,
but the problem is when i delete an item from the list last item of the list is rebuild and the timer of that item(last item) start over, what i should do to make the last item do not rebuild when iam deleting an item or how to deal with it.